# jQuery - Ability to Change an IMG Source, and show a loader until the image is loaded by the browser

Tags: jquery

I have a frame with an image tag inside, like a photo gallery

```
<div id="frame">
 <img src="yahoo.com/logo.gif" id="photo" />
</div>
```

With jQuery I'm going to dynamically change the img src to a different image URL.  This causes the frame to jump in height as the image dimensions are different. It also cause a flash as the browser loads the image. It's a bad experience.

What'd I'd like to know if is possible, is whenever the img src is changed, is for jQuery to show a default loader, and then once the image is fully loaded, then show the image and remove the loader.

Any suggestions? hopefully a plugin? thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
$('#frame > img').after('<img src="loading.jpg" />') // some preloaded "loading" image
                 .hide()
                 .attr('src','/some/new/value.jpg')
                 .one('load', function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn().next().remove();
                 });
```

- the [`after()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to insert a "loading" image (should be preloaded)
- the [`hide()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method to hide the current image
- the [`attr()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to change the `src`
- the [`one()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to bind a load event that will be removed once the image is loaded
- the [`fadeIn()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method to give a nice fade in effect once the image has loaded
- the [`next()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to get to the "loading" image
- the [`remove()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to remove the "loading" image

Answer (score 0):

You could probably preload the images, as described here: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

If you don't want your `frame` div to jump in height, you will need to set a fix height on the div that will fit all image sizes.